# Stop the audio, with or without the delay

Tags: java, android

I have a button. When I click on it, audio will be played. That audio will always be repeated with a delay. I.e. the audio will be played and then there is a pause for 5 seconds and then it will be played over and over again. So far, that works fine.

```java
public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
public View mView;
private Context mContext;
public boolean status;

public boolean getStatus() {
    return status;
}
public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void toggle(View view, Context context) {
    this.mView = view;
    this.mContext = context;

    // Activate the scanner
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        this.start();
    }
    // Deactivate the scanner
    else {
        this.stop();
    }

}

/**
 * Star the scanner
 */
@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForColorStateLists")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void start() {
    if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, scanner);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayerListener -> mediaPlayer.start());
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(listener -> Helper.setTimeout(() -> mediaPlayer.start(), 5000));
    }
}

/**
 * Stop the scanner
 */
@SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForColorStateLists")
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void stop() {
    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mView.setBackgroundTintList(null);
        Snackbar.make(mView, "Scanner is OFF", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        setStatus(false);
    }
}
```

```java
public static void setTimeout(Runnable runnable, int delay) {
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(runnable, delay);
}
```

### The Problem

I use `toggle()` for my button. So when I click on it, the audio will be played and when I click again, it should be stopped. That used to work fine, until I added `setOnCompletionListener()`. So now the audio will only stop when it is already playing. But when I click on that button during the 5000ms delay, it will not work.

I want my toggle button to work, with or without that delay. So is there a way I could cancel that CompletionListener?

Comment: We have no idea what Helper.setTimeout() does.  (Well I'm pretty sure I know what it does, but no idea which of the few dozen ways it could be working).  But basically, you need to cancel that timeout.  And how to do that (or even if its possible) depends on the method you're using there.  We can't help you without the code of Helper.setTimeout.

Comment: Also, you need to change the function in your setOnCompletionListener to NOT call the Helper at all if you canceled it via the button.  Because calling stop always calls the onCompletionListener.  That can be done by a simple flag-  set the flag when you press the button, check the flag in the setOnCompletionListener, then set the flag false at the end of the onCompleteionListener.

Comment: @GabeSechan `setTimeout()` is just the method for the delay. I have now updated my question.

Comment: Yeah, so you need to do what I described with the flag.   You also need to call removeMessage on that handler in case its already waiting to play a sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The interesting part of your code is `getStatus()`. You should make use of it. Somehow like this:

```java
public class Scanner {
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    public View mView;
    private Context mContext;
    public boolean status;
    private boolean mScannerIsWating = false;

    public boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(boolean status) {
        this.status = status;
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void toggle(View view, Context context) {
        this.mView = view;
        this.mContext = context;

        // Activate the scanner
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying() && !getStatus()) {
            this.start();
        }
        // Deactivate the scanner
        else if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying() || getStatus()) {
            this.stop();
        }

    }

    /**
     * Star the scanner
     */
    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForColorStateLists")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void start() {
        if (!mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            setStatus(true);
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(mContext, scanner);
            mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mediaPlayerListener -> mediaPlayer.start());
            int scanTimer = (!Objects.equals(Helper.getSharedPreference(mContext, "scanTimer"), "")) ? Integer.parseInt(Helper.getSharedPreference(mContext,"scanTimer")) * 1000 : 0;
            mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(listener -> Helper.setTimeout(() -> {
                if (getStatus()) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            }, scanTimer));

            // View
            mView.setBackgroundTintList(mView.getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.darkRed));
            Snackbar.make(mView, "Scanner is ON", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Stop the scanner
     */
    @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForColorStateLists")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void stop() {
        setStatus(false);
        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mView.setBackgroundTintList(null);
        Snackbar.make(mView, "Scanner is OFF", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
    }
}
```

Hint: You should remove `mediaPlayer.release()`, otherwise you may get an error when you stop and start the mediaplayer.